# Moving wordpress from local to local

Tags: php, wordpress, local

I have wordpress installed and running in my local machine with Windows and Xampp server. I want to access my site from all machines within my network. I have copied all the files with database dump, but it's not working. Posts, pages, plugins nothing are displaying.

I am new to wordpress, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  Why are you copying files around for example? Why not just create a file share if you want to edit the source and access it across your network. or if you want to access it via the web interface just point your web browser on machine 2 to the ip address off machine 1

Comment: You've said what you don't see.. What DO yo see?  Maybe some screenshots of each would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your local Wordpress installation (running on 127.0.0.1) work, is not necessary any modifications.
Just access from computers on LAN with ip machine

192.168.0.1/wordpress <- IP of XAMPP PC.